# How to match a pattern which doesn't include some char and has threshold?

Tags: python, regex

I have two strings:

```
a = "abcd,efghi" 
b = "abcdefghi"
```

Now I have a substring:

```
c = "abc"
```

and a postfix:

```
d = "ghi"
```

I just want to know how to write the regex to match the string b, which means the chars between c and d don't contain any puntuactions. And set a threshold between a and b, like {4,10}

I have tried:

```
"abc[^,]*?ghi"
```

But I don't konw how to set threshold!

Comment: your question is unclear, whats your desired output?

Comment: I want to match string b, but don't match string a.@SufiyanGhori

Answer (score 1):

You can create a capturing group for the string without double-quotes,

```
"([a-z]{4,10})"$
```

[Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Bduh2e/1/)

Comment: Why do some one think this answer is useful?